# PHP ArrayAccess - multidimensional array and offsetGet with reference

Tags: php, arrayaccess

I read a lot of past questions about `ArrayAccess` PHP interface and it's method `offsetGet` that can return a reference. I have a simple class implementing this interface that wraps a variable of type `array`. The `offsetGet` method returns a reference, however I get an error saying `Only variable references should be returned by reference`. Why?

```
class My_Class implements ArrayAccess {
    private $data = array();

    ...

    public function &offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset( $this->data[ $offset ] ) ? $this->data[ $offset ] : null;
    }

    ...
}
```

I would like to be able to use multidimensional arrays with this class:

```
$myclass = new My_Class();

$myclass['test'] = array();
$myclass['test']['test2'] = array();
$myclass['test']['test2'][] = 'my string';
```

Comment: Because you return `NULL` unbound to a variable, does it help if you rewrite it to `if(!isset( $this->data[ $offset ]) $this->data[ $offset ] = null; return $this->data[ $offset ];` ? /too lazy to test

Comment: Your function returns the result of an expression, not a reference. And a `& null` reference isn't possible. Try temporary variables.

Answer (score 1):

In this code :

```
public function &offsetGet($offset) {
    $returnValue = isset( $this->data[ $offset ] ) ? $this->data[ $offset ] : null;
    return $returnValue;
}
```

`$returnValue` is a copy of `$this->data[$offset]`, not a reference.

You have to make itself a reference, and for that you have to replace the ternary operator with an if statement :

```
public function &offsetGet($offset) {
    if (isset($this->data[$offset]) {
        $returnValue &= $this->data[$offset]; // note the &=
    }
    else {
        $returnValue = null;
    }
    return $returnValue;
}
```

should do the trick.

For the non-existent case, I'd rather throw an Exception, like the one you got when asking for a non-existing key of an array.
Since the value you return won't be a reference,

```
$myclass['non-existing']['test2'] = array();
```

will presumably throw an `indirect overloaded modification` error, and should therefore be forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is becuase you are returning the result of an expression, not a variable.
Try writing the if statement out and return the actual variable.

see [php manual -> second note](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

Answer (score 0):

The method '&offsetGet' is returning a reference (pointer) to a variable.

You need to either modify the method signature from '&offsetGet' to 'offsetGet' or use a variable to hold the return value.

```
// modify method signiture
public function offsetGet($offset) {
    return isset( $this->data[ $offset ] ) ? $this->data[ $offset ] : null;
}

// or use a variable to hold the return value.
public function &offsetGet($offset) {
    $returnValue = isset( $this->data[ $offset ] ) ? $this->data[ $offset ] : null;
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I can't use the first statement because it's returning a copy of the array instead of the original. The second statement is throwing a new error: Indirect modification of overloaded element of My_Class has no effect

Comment: Give me the context up the stack. Whats calling offsetGet?

Comment: It's in the question. I'm creating a new class instance and then trying to set some data in the array